# Unable to fetch the "valueOf" a moment date with IE8 (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, timestamp, momentjs

I'm facing a new IE problem. I'm using moment.js to handle dates in my webapp. I need to get the timestamp of some dates like :

```
var x = moment();
console.log(x.valueOf());
```

But under IE8 (the native one, or with IETester, it works well with the emulated IE8 version on IE10) I get the actual moment object instead of the timestamp in milliseconds.

I can't use standard javascript Dates.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys I found an alternative : under IE8 to get the timestamp of a moment :

```
var x = moment();
console.log(x.toDate().getTime());
```

There you go.